# java game programing enemy explosion

Tags: java, animation, graphics, repaint

hi i am creating a small game as a project.
the game resembles chicken invader.

the game is run by a gameLoop which constantly calls the render(Graphics g) method to paint changes and the tick() method that changes the x,y coordinates of all moving objects.

i have attempted to make my chickens expload on impact (change their picture to an exploasion)..
my problem is the change happens so fast the user cannot see it.

i have attempted to use the following:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                int temp = deleteExploasion;
                exploasions.get(temp).setExplosion(false);
                deleteExploasion++;
              }
            }, /*2*60*1000*/ 1500);
```

it sets a boolean on the chicken and in 1.5 seconds the chicken should in the next render method be painted back.
but i keep getting

```
Timer already cancelled.
at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
```

would appreciate help or advice on how to implement such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a `tick()` method to update the game you should also use it to handle your timer.

Create an `int` called delay or timer or something and reduce it in the `tick()` method then check if the timer is done and call your explosion or remove method.

Answer (score 0):

ok i have managed to solve this problem
i used this:

```
if(deleteExploasion == 0){
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
              exploasions = new LinkedList<Chicken>();
              }
            }, 2000, 2000);
        deleteExploasion++;
        }
```

basicly i deleted the chickens.
then i created exploasions LinkedList containing all the explosions (Images with x,y)
and i start the time cycle once and reset it every few seconds.

thanks alot for help 
and as was mentioned here this method is indeed in the render() method 
(just like tick() it is also called constantly).

if anyone sees a problem with my implementation would appriciate a comment.